# How does the "focus" flow in a document?

Tags: html, css

I have a rough idea that it hops from `<input>` to `<input>` but is there any documentation for it? My purpose was to look for a way to set focus only in css.

Comment: CSS `:focus` is a _selector_ that applies **when that element has focus**. I don't think there's a method that CSS can affect the _behavior_ of HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "focus" you mean the focused element when tabbing through elements in a rendered page, then the `tabindex=nn` attribute defines the tabbing order.

According to the [W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)

> The following elements support the tabindex attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA

See also [Creating Logical Tab Order with the Tabindex Attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Creating_Logical_Tab_Order_with_the_Tabindex_Attribute)

Comment: In html5, any elements can have the attribute `tabindex` set. It is not always useful though.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute